# cordova error running visual studio 2015 in parallels

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, parallels

- What went wrong:
  1>  Unable to start the daemon process.
  1>  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  1>  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  1>  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  1>  Please read the following process output to find out more:
  1>  -----------------------
  1>  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
  1>      at java.io.File.(File.java:423)
  1>      at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspathForClass(ClasspathUtil.java:67)
  1>      at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.findDistDir(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:75)
  1>      at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:55)
  1>      at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:44)
  1>      at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
  1>      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
  1>
  1>
  1>  * Try:
  1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Are you able to run the application using the Cordova command line?

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder sharing settings on the windows side of parallels. Does it work without sharing?